# Can't install e(fx)clipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bundle, equinox, efxclipse

I'm trying to install e(fx)clipse on eclipse 4.4 (luna), and I keep getting an error saying I'm missing a bundle (org.eclipse.equinox.common). I've tried installing various pieces of software from the Help>install new software menu using the download.eclipse.org/releases/luna directory, but I can't seem to find the software I need. The specific error code:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
Missing requirement: org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n 2.0.0.201506111511) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.equinox.common 3.7.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n.feature.feature.group [2.0.0.201506111511]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - l10n support 2.0.0.201506111511 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201506111511)
To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.l10n [2.0.0.201506111511]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is telling you that you need version 3.7.0 of `org.eclipse.equinox.common`. Eclipse Luna only has version 3.6.0 of the plugin you need to use Eclipse Mars which has version 3.7.0

Comment: can i install the plugin separately? or do i need to use a completely different version of eclipse/install the whole thing?

Comment: It will probably have dependencies on many other Eclipse Mars plugins so no stick to a full install. The [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) site covers installs.